# Arc length of a parabola

Tags: calculus

Let be $c:[0,a]\to \mathbb{R}$ with
$$c(t)=(t,t^2)$$
and I should calculate the arc length of the parabola.

Hint: Use $\sqrt{1+\tau^2}d\tau = \cosh \sigma\cdot \mathrm{d}\sinh\sigma.$

How can I integrate

$$\int\limits_0^a \sqrt{1+4t^2} dt = \int\limits_0^a \cosh(2t)\ \mathrm{d}\sinh(2t)?$$

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking how to get that left-hand integral, why it equals the right-hand integral, how to evaluate either integral, or some combination?

Comment: Useful links: http://www.math.drexel.edu/~tolya/arc_length_x%5E2.pdf and http://planetmath.org/arclengthofparabola

Answer (score 0):

I've got following answer:

\begin{align*}
c([0,a]) &= \int\limits_0^a \cosh(2t)\ \mathrm{d}\sinh(2t) \\
&\overset{(1)}{=} 2\int\limits_0^a \cosh^2(2t) dt \\
&\overset{u=2t}{\underset{du=2dt}{=}} \int\limits_0^{2a} \cosh^2(u)du\\
&=\int_0^{2a}\left(\frac{1}{2}\cosh(2u)+\frac{1}{2}\right)du \\
&=\left[\frac{u}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\sinh(2u)\right]_0^{2a}\\
&=a+\frac{1}{4}\sinh(4a),
\end{align*}
while
$$\frac{d\sinh(2t)}{dt}=2\cosh(2t)\Longleftrightarrow d\sinh(2t)=2\cosh(2t)dt.\tag{1}$$