# Divide a parabola in segments of equal length

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I have a parabola defined as:
$$ y = \frac{4H}{L^2}x(L-x)$$
which corresponds to an arch with $x\in[0,L]$ and $y\in[0,H]$.

I'm trying to divide this parabola in N segments of equal length. My thought was to compute the function $x(s)$, which is the $x$ value of the point in the parabola at an arc-length of s from the start of the parabola at $x=0$. And then simply have a uniform spacing of values of $s$ and get the corresponding values of $x$ and $y$.

The inverse function $s(x)$ can be computed by noting that:
$$s(x)=\int_0^x\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx$$
where $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{4H}{L^2}(L-2x)$. However, this results in a complicated function that I cannot invert.

Is there another way to obtain an even division of the parabola? An analytical solution would be ideal, but a numerical solution would also be acceptable.

Comment: You might translate the parabola and use the answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1730258/arc-length-of-a-parabola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was inspired by Paul Sinclair suggestion to use the Newton method to compute this numerically. I post below my derivation followed by my algorithm for those interested.

### Derivation:

Start by computing the arc-length function $s(x)$ as described in the question formulation and dividing the resulting function by $s(L)$ to normalize it. After some simplification we get:

$$\bar{s} = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{f(X)}{f(a)}\right)$$
where $\bar{s}\in[0,1]$ is the normalized arclength, $a=\frac{4H}{L}$, $X=a(1-2\bar{x})$, $\bar{x}=x/L$ is the normalized $x$ coordinate and
$$f(x)=x\sqrt{1+x^2}+\sinh^{-1}(x)$$

Trying to solving for $X$ given $\bar{s}$ is equivalent to finding the root of:
$$r(X) = f(X) - \left(1-2\bar{s}\right)f(a) =0$$

The derivative of $r(X)$ is:
$$J(X) = \frac{dr}{dX} =  \frac{df}{dX} = 2\sqrt{1+X^2}$$

Now we have all the ingredients to apply the newton method.

### Algorithm:

Overall algorithm:

1. Given $H$ and $L$, compute $a$.
2. Generate list of $\bar{s}$ by spanning the range $[0,1]$.
3. Compute $\bar{x}$ for each $\bar{s}$ using the Newton algorithm.
4. For each $\bar{x}$ compute $x=\bar{x}L$ and $y=4H\bar{x}(1-\bar{x})$.

Newton Algorithm:

1. Set X=0
2. Compute $r(X)$
3. Compute $J(X)$
4. $X = X - r(X)/J(X)$
5. Compute $r(X)$
6. If $|r(X)|>$ tolerance, then go back to step 3.
7. $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{X}{a}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

If we flip your parabola over and shift it to the left
$$x' = x -\frac L2\\y' = H - y$$ your parabola becomes $$y' = \frac {4H}{L^2}x'^2$$. Since the transformation is rigid, we haven't changes the arclengths. Now the base of your parabola was at $(0,0)$ and $(L,0)$. These points have moved to $\left(\pm\frac L2, H\right)$. If we let $a = \frac{4H}{L^2}$ then we can use [this calculation](https://planetmath.org/arclengthofparabola) to obtain

$$s = \frac 1{4a}\left(2ax'\sqrt{4a^2x'^2 + 1} + \sinh^{-1} 2ax'\right)$$
for the arclength $s$ from the apex to the point $(x', y')$. Letting $x' = \frac L2$, we get the full arclength on one side to be
$$S = \sqrt{H^2 + \frac{L^2}{16}} + \frac {L^2}{16H}\sinh^{-1}\frac{4H}L$$
Now you want to divide the full length of this parabola into $N$ parts. If $N$ is even, then set $d = \frac {2S}N$, and find the points that are a distance $kd$ away from the apex on the curve for $1 \le k < \frac N2$. If $N$ is odd, let $d = \frac SN$, and find the points that are a distance $(2k - 1)d$ from the apex on the curve, for $1 \le k <\frac N4$.

There is no nice closed form for the inverse of $s$, so you will need to use numerical methods to find the $x'$ values. Newton's Method should work fine, though the derivative is not nice.